# Jersey REST WS Error: "Missing dependency for method... at parameter at index X"

Tags: java, rest, jersey, media-type

I am getting the following error:

```
Apr 09, 2013 12:24:26 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.package.ImportService.specifyLocalFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 0
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.package.ImportService.specifyLocalFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 1
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.package.ImportService.specifyLocalFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 2
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.package.ImportService.specifyLocalFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 3
SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.package.ImportService.specifyLocalFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String), annotated with POST of resource, class com.package.ImportService, is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

I have a previously working POST method that takes a Multipart data (a file upload) and then some other String data fields from the submitted form, here's the code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
    @FormDataParam("param1") String param1,
    @FormDataParam("param2") String param2,
    @FormDataParam("param3") String param3) {
    ....
    ....
    return Response.status(200).entity(getEntity()).build();
}
```

The error seems to be related to the way the form parameters are being interpreted by Jersey. here's the code that fails:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("/local")
public Response specifyLocalFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") String fullFilePath,
    @FormDataParam("param1") String param1,
    @FormDataParam("param2") String param2,
    @FormDataParam("param3") String param3) {
    ....
    ....
    return Response.status(200).entity(getEntity()).build();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After googling a little I end up reviewing some interesting cases, such as [Failed unmarshalling issue with @FormParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024408/jax-rs-exception-annotated-with-get-of-resource-class-is-not-recognized-as-val), or [Missing mulipart JAR dependency issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203391/formdataparam-throws-severe-missing-dependency) the most aproximate post for my problem was this: ["Missing dependecy for method"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262610/missing-dependecy-for-method), which I answer with a link to this POST, as I see no currenty solution for that particular one.

The issue appeared to be related to the `@FormDataParam` annotation, when used with the method-level `@Consumes` annotation with the value `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`.

When I changed the Method signature to annotate each plain-text field with `@FormParam`, the exception was gone. Check the fixed code below:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("/local")
public Response specifyLocalFile()
    @FormParam("file") String fullFilePath,
    @FormParam("param1") String param1,
    @FormParam("param2") String param2,
    @FormParam("param3") String param3) {
    ....
```

If the type of the data being received does not have to deal with MIME-encodings, the `@FormParam` annotation will attempt to deal with the contents via serialization; in contrast, the `@FormDataParam` annotation requires some specific handling that is configured when the `@Consumes` annotation has the `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error on my project.

1) you need to put all jersey dependencies to the same version.

2) I had also problem because of swagger anotations @ApiParam :

```
@ApiParam(value = "import file", required = true) @FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStreamCsv
```

Removing them did the trick :

```
@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStreamCsv
```

here is the link mentionning the problem : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1530

Finally, everything worked with this :

```
@POST
@Path("/import")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response import(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStreamCsv,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition detailsFichier) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference: In my case it was the depency `jersey-multipart`, used in a different version than the other Jersey libs, causing this error in connection with multipart form data. --> make sure to use the same version number for all Jersey libs! (`mvn dependency:tree` is your friend)