# jersey server missing dependencies

Tags: java, jersey, dependencies, server

I'm using this code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/files")
public class JerseyFileUpload {

    private static final String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "C://Users/nikos/Desktop/Upload_Files/";

    /**
     * Upload a File
     */

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {

        String filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER
                + contentDispositionHeader.getFileName();

        // save the file to the server
        saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

        String output = "File saved to server location : " + filePath;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

    // save uploaded file to a defined location on the server
    private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String serverLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    serverLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            outpuStream.flush();
            outpuStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

When I try to run it on Apache Tomcat I get these error messages:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.JerseyFileUpload.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.JerseyFileUpload.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.JerseyFileUpload.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition), annotated with POST of resource, class com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.JerseyFileUpload, is not recognized as valid resource method.
Nov 19, 2014 11:44:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4932)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5218)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 19, 2014 11:44:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /asdf threw load() exception
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4932)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5218)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:74
```

What does this mean? How can I fix these dependencies?

Thanks in advance!

**UPD 0**
Dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>JAXRS-HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your dependencies...

Comment: I think you are missing the `@FormDataParam("data") FileData bean` parameter in your method which is rendering it invalid. Refer https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.5/contribs/jersey-multipart/com/sun/jersey/multipart/FormDataParam.html.

Comment: Also, you might be missing the jersey-core dependency.

Comment: I've added dependencies for jersey-core but again same thing.

Comment: What steps are you taking to deploy this?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the jars aren't getting transferred to Tomcat when you deploy it. One thing I can see being a problem, is that you are missing the `<packaging>`in your `pom.xml`. If this is missing, the default will be to build a `.jar`. What you need is a `.war` where the dependencies are put into `WEB-INF/lib`.

So add `<packaging>war</packaging>` right under your project `<version>`. Clean and package the project. Then you should get a `.war` file. If you explode the `.war`, you should see the `WEB-INF/lib`. This is the standard place for webapp dependencies. Without exploding it, you can simply add the war to to the Tomcat `webapp` dir and when you start Tomcat, it should explode the `.war` and should be able to find the libraries there.

I had no problem running your example after adding this.

Comment: How can I run the project after it is compressed to .war?

Comment: Put it into `{tomcatHome}\webapps`. When the Tomcat is started it should explode the war. Say the war is `your-project.war`, the war will get exploded to a dir `your-project`. You should see the `WEB-INF\lib` with all the dependencies

Comment: This is a headache to keep copying and pasting the war back and forth to the server (during development). Any good IDE should have this facility to set up the run configuration to deploy to the server.

Comment: Did you look in the WEB-INF\lib to make sure all the jars are there?

Comment: The Jersey library is dependent on asm, which seems not to be on the class path. If it is in the WEB-INF\lib of your project, then it will be put on the classpath

Comment: Yes all jars are there.

Comment: I have jersey-bundle jar instead of all jars separate.

Comment: With the two dependencies you have posted in your Maven pom.xml, it should have pulled in _all_ these.. 1) `jersey-multipart-1.9` 2) `jersey-server-1.9` 3) `asm-3.1` 4) `jersey-core-1.9` 5) `mime-pull-1.6`. These are all needed

Comment: I didn't test with `jersey-bundle.jar`. I just tested with the two dependencies you have posted in your pom.xml in your post. Try it with what you have in your original post

Comment: I have `jersey-bundle-1.18.jar` and `jersey-media-multipart-2.2-sources.jar` in WEB-INF/lib folder. Is this sufficient for application to run properly?

Comment: Are you using Maven to build?

Comment: I think so. But where can I check that? I'm making project in Eclipse JavaEE.

Comment: How exactly are you building the project? How did you create it?

Comment: I've created new dynamic web project in eclipse. And I just click `Publish to server` to update changes I've made.

Comment: That `pom.xml` file you have is a Maven file. If you created a Maven project in your IDE, this file should have been created for you. If you just copied and pasted that file from somewhere, then you may not be using Maven

Comment: Yea that's not a Maven Project. Here [download this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm/3.1). This is a missing jar.

Comment: Yes I copied that from internet. How can I make project that works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65216/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-acac97).

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue has been addressed here 
[Jersey REST WS Error: "Missing dependency for method... at parameter at index X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909978/jersey-rest-ws-error-missing-dependency-for-method-at-parameter-at-index-x)