# Maven jersey-multipart missing dependency for javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jersey

I seem to have a missing dependency but can't find the solution...
I've made sure all jersey versions are identical as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203391/formdataparam-throws-severe-missing-dependency).

Error:

```
  SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public abstract javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.service.copy(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 0
```

Dependencies used:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code where the error happens:

```
@POST
@Path("copy")
public Response copy(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail);
```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah found it!

Apparently the dependencies were OK.

Added these to my imports

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
```

And changed the code to

```
@POST
@Path("copy")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response copy(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail);
```

And now suddenly everything works!
So hope I can help someone else with the same problem...

Answer (score 3):

`@FormDataParam` seems to be very fussy about the `@Consumes` annotation. Note that (unlike just about everything else) placing this annotation on an interface definition of the method isn't good enough for `@FormDataParam` !